# Delete rows from table corresponding to selected checkboxes on click on delete

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, checkbox

I am using codeigniter framework for my website. In views I have a php file which displays a table like this:

```
            #        Name

checkbox    1   Aanchal 


checkbox    2   Abhijeet
```

Now i want to get id of all the selected checkboxes (can be multiple also) such that when the user click on delete button present in navigation bar, the selected entries get deleted.

Here is the code I am using in views:

```
<header class="jumbotron subhead" id="overview">
    <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="controller 1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="controller 2">Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="controller 3">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="controller 4">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="content" style="height: 500px; width: 800px">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($json_string);$i++)
        {       
            $sno = $i + 1;
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id=<?php $sno?> value=<?php $sno?> /><br />
        </td>
        <td><?php print_r($sno)?></td>
        <td><?php print_r($json_string[$i]->fName);
        if(isset($json_string[$i]->lName))
        {
            print_r($json_string[$i]->lName);
        }
        else
            print_r("");
        ?>
        </td>
    </tbody>
        </table>
```

Controller 4 will be having code to delete the selected entries from string, so what should I do to get and pass the selected checkboxes' ids to controller 4

Comment: probable duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112863/how-to-get-checkbox-values-using-php-code-ignitor-in-controller

Answer (score 0):

Set checkbox attribute "name", for example will looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="itemIds[]" id=<?php $sno?> value=<?php $sno?> />
```

Also add form and put table inside this form. Then on delete button click submit form, so in post data you will get checked items values

Comment: will this work even if my delete button is not in form. and can you please paste code snippet for better understanding

Comment: you can put button outside form also simple link or div element, and add click event, for example jquery form submit onclick="$('#frmTable').submit();"

Comment: <form name="frmTable" id="frmTable" method="post">Your table content</form> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#frmTable').submit();">Delete</a>

Comment: but how will it post the checked values to a function in controller ??

Comment: Look this topics and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522070/php-checkbox-multiple-delete, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529005/php-multiple-checkbox-delete